# Close popup on cancel of javascript button.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In one modal popup, I am updating values, and upon save button click, before updating I am asking user by javascript message box : "Are you sure....?"

This I am doing by following code:

```
 btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " & "confirm('Are you sure " & RbtnConfirm.SelectedValue & " ' )")
```

But when user clicks cancel, I want to close that whole modal popup by:

`modalpopup1.hide()` method

I am confused how and where should I include this line of code?

From where can I get whether `btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " & "confirm('Are you sure " & RbtnConfirm.SelectedValue & " ' )")` has returned false or true?

Please help me.

Comment: For future reference, please tag correctly. Don't add every tag you can think of, add the tags that have relevance to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why the `return " & "`?

Anyway for inline (which is not recommended), just do

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (confirm('Are you sure " & RbtnConfirm.SelectedValue & " ' )) modalpopup1.hide()")
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the confirm call to separate function, ie.:

include this in your .ascx/.aspx:

```
<script>
  function myconfirm(sValue) {
     var bValue = confirm(sValue);
     if (!bValue) {
       modalpopup1.hide();
     }
     return bValue;
  }
</script>
```

in codebehind:

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " & "myconfirm('Are you sure " & RbtnConfirm.SelectedValue & " ' )")
```